# Query performance difference between fixed value and table

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

The following query returns results in less than 1 second:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IndicatorID
FROM dbo.tblData
WHERE tblData.RevisionID in (1)
```

The following query produces the same results, but takes at least 5 seconds to return:

```
DECLARE @Revisions AS TABLE
(
    number INT PRIMARY KEY
)
INSERT INTO @Revisions
SELECT 1

SELECT DISTINCT IndicatorID
FROM dbo.tblData
WHERE tblData.RevisionID in (SELECT number FROM @Revisions)
```

This was an example of the scenario I have.

Doing a `JOIN` makes no difference.
Using a temp table (#) and creating a `UNIQUE INDEX` makes no difference either.

I imagine the problem is not in tblData, since using the fixed value '1' it runs very fast.

Execution plan:
[image: Execution Plan]

UPDATE:
Execution Plan with index with RevisionID only:
[image: Execution Plan with IX RevisionID]

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans?

Comment: @hatchet Yes, just attached to the question. I still don't see the reason for the difference!

Comment: The first one with the literal is equivalent to `where RevisionId=1`. The second one because the optimizer makes fewer assumptions about the table var than it can make about the literal is much more complex. This may give you some things to try: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35990/join-to-a-table-variable-is-running-ineficiently

Comment: You could use `forceseek` or `loop join` hints to get the plan you want but if the table variable ever has a much greater number of rows that hint can backfire.

Comment: Hi @igorjrr,
That is the another example of "keep the query in simplest form" and if any issue arise then look for alternatives. IF you will look in the execution plan there is a HASH MATCH for distinct values(this is the problematic part), and then joining the table, i have tested it and this scenario arsies when probe input is huge, for smaller table its joining first then distincting rows later. if you are forced to use table variable or temp table look into martin smith comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check these:

1. What's the data type of tblData.RevisionID. make sure it's the same as your 'number' field (INT).
2. I am assuming that the index tblData.IX_IndicatorRevision is a composite index with RevisionID as the second field. create an index on RevisionID to avoid the Index Scan which is the worst offender based on the execution plan.

Comment: It is the same type, int. Created an index on RevisionID, still the first query (fixed value) runs super quick, but the second one still takes more than 5 seconds.

Comment: can you attach the new execution plan?

Comment: @IIan Done! Looks same execution plan, but using the new index instead. Still taking more than 4 seconds to execute.